# Kotlin -How to Change the Color Tint of an Image inside a Button to Another Color Tint and Back

Tags: android, image, kotlin, button, colors

I have a button that has a red and black image inside of it. When the button is pressed I want to change the color of the image tint to gray and when it is pressed again I want to remove the gray color. The image tine should go back to its original color.

XML:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/camera_button"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/red_and_black_camera_button_icon"
/>
```

Activity:

```
var changeColor = false

fun cameraButtonTapped() {

   changeColor = !changeColor

   // I know this doesn't work. This is one of the many ways I tried
   binding.camera_button.backgroundTintList = if(changeColor) ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.gray)) else null
}
```

Comment: I bet it would be easier if you change the whole image/background and to do so swap the image between two that you have pre computed with tints

Comment: thanks for the advice. I actually thought about doing that but I thought it seemed like overkill to do something that seems so trivial. I'm really an iOS developer learning Android. In iOS this would be a 1-2-3 thing. This is complicated for no reason. Cheers!

Comment: @LanceSamaria where do you change `changeCameraButtonColor`? will it solve your problem if you replace `changeColor = !changeCameraButtonColor` with `changeColor = !changeColor`?

Comment: @VladGuriev hi, this has nothing to do with toggling the Boolean. This is about physically changing the tint color of the image inside the button. Thanks for pointing that out though, it was a typo on my part. I'll update it for more clarity

Answer (score 0):

1- To get around this issue I used an `ImageView` instead and set its `src` property to the camera button image:

XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/camera_button_iv"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:src="@drawable/red_and_black_camera_button_icon"
/>
```

2- In `res/colors` I added a clear color

```
<color name="clearColor">#00000000</color>
```

3- In the Activity I toggle the imageView's `.setColorFilter()` to either color. This changes the image's tint color to gray and when the clearColor is added it goes back to red and black.

```
var changeColor = false

fun cameraButtonTapped() {

   changeColor = !changeColor

   val grayColor = ContextCompat.getColor(binding.root.context, R.color.gray)
   val clearColor = ContextCompat.getColor(binding.root.context, R.color.clearColor)

   binding.camera_button_iv.setColorFilter(if (changeColor) grayColor else clearColor)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that the image should initially be white,

```
<ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/camera_button"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/red_and_black_camera_button_icon"
            app:tint="@color/red"/>
```

and then you set the desired color like this

```
binding.camera_button.setColorFilter(Color.GRAY)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var flag=false 

btn.setOnClickListener{
 flag=!flag
 if(flag)
    it.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
 else
    it.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**